# Querying Posts Using JSON API

Tags: api, json

I am looking at the WordPress JSON API Plugin. What I'd like to do is query all posts in a custom taxonomy term called `wales`. I have been able to get all posts in the post type listings using this url -

```
/?json=get_posts&post_type=listings
```

But how would I retrieve all posts in a custom taxonomy term?

I have attempted this -

```
http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/?json=get_posts&taxonomy=area&term=wales&post_type=listings
```

Comment: Before someone else gets here, I should remind you that plugin specific questions aren't great round these parts... Also, WP 4.4 includes a JSON API in core now. http://v2.wp-api.org If you can't find something you need you can create custom endpoints - http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

Comment: On a side note, WPEngine was hacked today so be sure to change all your passwords - https://wpengine.com/support/infosec/

Comment: Check out http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/ to see where your endpoints start.

Comment: Thats great, thank you for your suggestions. I have heard about the hack but thank you for the reminder. I will check out your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I found this this url got me the results I needed -

```
http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/posts?type=listings&filter[listing_area]=channel
```

my post type being `listings` and the slug of my term `channel`